# WCF service not invoked by client

Tags: wcf-client

I am working on my first WCF service and i am not sure why there are no results inspite of doing every correct.

Created a WCF service.Added a .svc page as well and now i can publish and browse to my service as well when it is hosted on IIS. Now i add service reference into a simple console application and create client object, provided values mandated by the data contract and then i do `client.Operationname()`.

What is supposed to happen is that my service is supposed to send an email out to the email address i provided during my testing with a confirmation message.But that does not happen.

- I enabled logging using `SvcConfigEditor` on the published config file, but there is no log entry.
- I checked the logs of smtp and nothing is there as well.

I am running out of ideas as what else can i do to make sure that i am able to send out the confirmation email to the customer using my service. Also my service does work when i have it published on local machine.

Comment: ???, Only a big block of text is difficult to read. [http://tinyurl.com/so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WcfTestClient.exe from Visual Studio.Net Command-line to help simulate the client. then, You can debug the server side code.